# How to count run queue average for last X minutes in Linux with C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, linux, system-administration

Current run queue number is located in /proc/stat, as procs_running, I can read this value or I can go through every /proc/pid/stat and count every process in R state, this way I can get instant number of runnable processes, but I don't see any way how can I calculate average number since it seems impossible to count average since number of runnables changes every microsecond. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: There is a way: you take a snapshot of the state and don't work with everchanging variables.

Comment: The keyword is *sampling*. You *sample* the run queue length every *x* msec.

Comment: Once you collect your samples, be sure to plot a histogram of them to make sure they seem sane.  The shape of the distribution might influence what notion of 'average' you chose. (mean, median, mode, etc)

Comment: C or C++? They are not the same language. Pick one.